# What Paragraphs and Line Breaks are valid RSS formatting? 

Tags: rss, standards-compliance

What html formatting for paragraphs, line breaks, lists, etc are valid in an RSS feed? Im pretty sure divs aren't allowed, but what about ul and li?

I know the theory is that the RSS readers will style the content and you shouldn't go overboard styling it yourself, but what about headings, paragraphs, lists, etc?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the `<description>` element of an RSS feed specifically? Because really, you should just encode any HTML, etc. in there as CDATA, at which point it won't affect the *validity* of your RSS. I have a suspicion that your question might actually be "what HTML will RSS readers generally render successfully once it's been extracted from the RSS feed for display?"

Comment: So lets say you just had 2 paragraphs of text, would you need to use CDATA to included them in p tags? I assumed their would be some default RSS formatting, but is ALL formatting done via CDATA? Thanks

Comment: If you want to include HTML, such as paragraph tags, in your RSS document, then yes, you'll need to include them as character data. The `<p>` element is not part of RSS, so if you include them directly as elements within your `<description>` element, for example, your RSS will be invalid. If you include the entire `<description>` text within a CDATA section or otherwise escape the contained HTML, it will be valid.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So how do I find the answer to "what HTML will RSS readers generally render successfully once it's been extracted from the RSS feed for display?" Ive googled this a bit but im not sure sure what to type in. Thanks

Comment: You know, that's a good question. I'd have expected there to be something out there to answer "What HTML is supported by popular RSS aggregators?", but I don't see anything. So I won't answer as I'd only be guessing! My RSS readers seem to at least successfully *style* (with their own styles, I'm guessing) and display headings, paragraphs, line breaks, lists, images, and bold/italic, etc. But it'd be interesting to see whether anyone's done any research on what popular supporters support what and how.

Comment: OK. Thanks for all your help and hopefully someone else can shed a little more light on this....

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the valid HTML tags in RSS Feeds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140307/what-are-the-valid-html-tags-in-rss-feeds)