# How can you insert an iframe into XML?

Tags: xml, iframe, rss, ads

How can you insert an iframe into XML?

I am looking to display ads in an RSS feed. Since the RSS is displaying XMl, I need to be able to put an iframe in my XML.

Comment: Ads in feeds are done with `<img>` tags AFAIK.

Comment: Do we get a share of the cut?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll - if I just place an image in my XML, how can I track the unique viewers, and unique clicks?

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert iframes into RSS feeds.

Or at least you'll have to do some digging into which particular few, if any, readers will actually render this for you.

There's *some* [formatting available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140307/what-are-the-valid-html-tags-in-rss-feeds) [for text in the](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/encodingDescriptions.html) `<description>` element, but your luck on getting iframes to work depends on what RSS reader is willing to show that.

For tracking purposes, it's just not going to be possible. You could try and guess the browser stats or referrer (don't rely on this, it can be forged or explicitly blanked out) if they click through or call up an image you've placed in there perhaps.